# Pegar selector de um plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Estou tentando criar um plugin mas não consigo pegar o [`selector`](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#selector-property-on-jquery-objects), e ele ainda foi removido da versão 1.9.

Se eu usar `$(this).selector` no plugin, ele retorna uma string `#div #elementoA, #div #elementoB`. Já tentei usar `this.each` pra tentar pegar individualmente, mas não consegui.

Preciso de uma forma que retorne ou um array, ou um objeto, mas com os selector's individuais: `'[#div #elementoA] [#div #elementoB]`. É possível usando o 1.9?

```
$('#div #elementoA, #div #elementoB').plugin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que não tem mais jeito.

A [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) inclusive dá um exemplo onde um plugin que precisa saber do seletor deve recebê-lo **repetido** como um parâmetro da função.

Exemplo de declaração:

```
$.fn.foo = function( selector, options ) { /* código */ };
```

Exemplo de chamada:

```
$( "div.bar" ).foo( "div.bar", {dog: "bark"} );
```

Não é uma resposta satisfatória, mas é a resposta oficial.

Creio que o melhor seria reformular seu código para não depender do seletor, se possível, caso contrário seria possível criar uma alternativa mais *bonita* do que a repetição. Um exemplo bem simples e pouco sofisticado seria:

```
function applyPlugin(selector, options) {
    $(selector).plugin(selector, options);
}
```

Se possível, edite a pergunta explicando exatamente o que você não conseguiu fazer com com o [`each`](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method).

De qualquer forma, fica o modelo do uso do `each`:

```
$.fn.myNewPlugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // ação em cada elemento aqui
    });
};
```

Comment: O `each` seria apenas para tentar pegar o selector de forma individual. Nunca criei um plugin, o que estou fazendo é um aprendizado, mas de forma geral eu chamo `$('#div #A, #div #B').plugin()` e dentro do plugin   eu uso `.attr('id')` pra trabalhar o `CSS`. Certamente estou fazendo errado, por isso queria tentar pegar o `selector`. Mas vou tentar aprender melhor. Valeu pela resposta.

Comment: Uma GAMB que eu fiz foi dar um `split` : `$(this).selector.split( ', ' )`. Retornou um array como queria, mas gambiarra é gambiarra né, nunca se sabe... rs

Comment: @papacharlie mas pra que exatamente vc precisa dos seletores? Se é apenas para aprendizado o split deve funcionar bem, talvez com uma expressão regular mais avançada fique mais confiável.

Comment: O seletor `#div #elementoA` me daria a garantia de somente esse elemento ser manipulado. Não é nada complexo, é falta de conhecimento mesmo.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Já pensou em contar o número de elementos? Por quê é importante garantir que somente um elemento está sendo manipulado?

Comment: Coloquei os links dentro de um `element` e nele eu faço um loop para pegar cada item. TKS